# Is there a way to trigger an error in Stylus when missing a variable?

Tags: gulp, stylus

I recently migrated from Sass to Stylus, and I'm loving it.

However, there is 1 thing that really made sense in Sass that doesn't exist in stylus. The compiler should yell at me if a variable is undefined, instead of just spitting it out as a string like nothing ever happened.

Is there a way to make the compiler yell at me ?

Comment: Workaround: use a linter on the generated css. Unresolved vars will almost certainly produce errors/warnings. Only downside is you have to figure out the location in your stylus files from the error location in your css.

Comment: That actually sounds like a decent workaround. You should have posted that as an answer :)

Comment: Eh, it's kind of an ugly hack, didn't feel right to post it as an answer. BTW there's also [`stylint`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylint), a linter for stylus files, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to throw an error/warning  for missing vars either (although I haven't tried every option). Might be more appropriate to request this feature there than in the stylus compiler itself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all options are in [this page](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/executable.html), you cannot do what you want at the moment.

You can still add this feature yourself or request it (by creating an issue) on the official [github repo](https://github.com/stylus/stylus)

By the way, this would be a good feature.